# Compile ImageMagick in a single DLL

Tags: c++, imagemagick

My application is built with C++/MFC and links dynamically with ImageMagick. I have to deploy 130 (!) ImageMagick DLLs alongside my files when installing the app!

I would like to have a single DLL for the entire ImageMagick library instead of 130. Any ideas for how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLL uses the serach path. Place the ImageMagick.DLL in one directory that is included in the PATH.

If that's not possible, you can change the PATH variable. Add a path to the directory where one instance of the DLL resides.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, nobody ever complains about having to run their code on an operating system that has three thousand DLLs.  Deploying one DLL isn't any easier than deploying 130 of them.  Your customer won't mind.  Hacking a library whose source code changes so frequently is something you'll regret deeply some day.

Comment: I know the end user doesn't mind, but hey I'm a perfectionist and I do mind :)